# Searching for simply apparently random sequence in $(0,1)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm searching for a simple sequence with the following properties, which I encountered years ago, but now I cannot find it (or build it):

- it's from $(0,1) \to (0, 1)$, in other words: $x_i \in (0,1)$
- in $(0,1)$ there is at most one fixpoint
- all elements in $(0,1)$ appear with equal probability (I know this is not precisely formulated; what I mean is that a histogram with arbitrary many bars will become flat if sufficiently many numbers are generated, starting from any point except the potential fixpoint).

I vaguely remember that the formula is as simple as $x_{i+1} = 1 - x_i^2$, if this is of any help. I found this sequence as an example of an *apparently* random sequence (if you just plot it, it seems like white noise), which is however perfectly predictable.

Comment: Is it perhaps this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map ?

Comment: It is definitively a good starting point! It is not identically distributed, however, I'll look at Wikipedia to see if I find something there. Thank you!

Comment: Working through it, I think I might have mixed it up: what I was looking for was the logistic map, but the properties I searched for were from the tent map  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tent_map with parameter $\mu$ approaching 2. The output of the tent map with $\mu = 2- \epsilon$ is approx. equally distributed and has zero autocorrelation ("white noise" for simplified linear statistical analysis), but is deterministic. 
If you could create an answer, I'd accept it :)